# Shared memory vs. Go channel communication

Tags: go, ipc, shared-memory, channel, goroutine

One of Go's slogans is [Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#concurrency).

I am wondering whether Go allows two different Go-compiled binaries running on the same machine to communicate with one another (i.e. client-server), and how fast that would be in comparison to boost::interprocess in C++? All the examples I've seen so far only illustrate communication between same-program routines.

A simple Go example (with separate client and sever code) would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

One of the first things I thought of when I read this was Stackless Python. The channels in Go remind me a *lot* of Stackless Python, but that's likely because (a) I've used it and (b) the language/thoughts that they *actually* came from I've never touched.

I've never attempted to use channels as IPC, but that's probably because the alternative is likely much safer.  Here's some psuedocode:

#### program1

```
chan = channel()
ipc = IPCManager(chan, None)
send_to_other_app(ipc.underlying_method)

chan.send("Ahoy!")
```

#### program2

```
chan = channel()
recv_from_other_app(underlying_method)
ipc = IPCManager(chan, underlying_method)

ahoy = chan.recv()
```

If you use a traditional IPC method, you can have channels at each side that wrap their communication on top of it.  This leads to some issues in implementation, which I can't even think about how to tackle, and likely a few unexpected race conditions.

However, I agree; the ability to communicate via processes using the same flexibility of Go channels would be phenomenal (but I fear unstable).

Wrapping a simple socket with channels on each side gets you almost all of the benefits, however.

Answer (score 3):

Rob has said that they are thinking a lot about how to make channels work as a (network) transparent RPC, this doesn't work at the moment, but obviously this is something they want to take the time to get it **right**.

In the meantime you can use [the gob package](http://golang.org/pkg/gob/) which, while not a perfect and seamless solution, works quite well already.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at doing a similar thing for wrapping the MPI library. My current thinking is to use something like

```
func SendHandler(comm Comm){
    // Look for sends to a process
    for {
        i := <-comm.To;
        comm.Send(i,dest);  
    }
}
func ReceiveHandler(comm Comm){
    // Look for recieves from a process
    // Ping the handler to read out
    for {
        _ = <-comm.From;
        i := comm.Recv(source);
        comm.From <- i;
     }
}
```

where comm.Send and comm.Recv wrap a c communications library. I'm not sure how you do the setting up of a channel for two different programs though, I've no experience in that sort of thing.